# How to display particular country map in React Native

Tags: react-native, maps, react-native-maps, react-native-mapbox-gl

Is there any way to display only a particular country (either USA or UK or India) using react-native-mapbox-gl/maps & react-native-map.

Using the above libraries I am able to display world map but my requirement here is to display only a particular country map.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend take a look at this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps), it's very simple to use and have a good documentation.

Comment: I have already seen the package which you have mentioned. But here my requirement is to show only a specific country say Germany .

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Because I don't know if you are trying to show a country spoted in the map or show the country map

Comment: If you could send a sketch or something that may help

Comment: what I am trying to achieve here is , using react-native-maps or react-native-mapbox-gl I want to display only a specific country (Germany). But by default the mentioned packages are displaying all countries and I need to set coordinates of a country which I want to.